# How to select row with same value

Tags: html, mysql, sql

I'm having a problem which is as follows. I've got a table with 5 *COLUMNS*: id, name, rating, sport and value. Now, I want to select the rows where names and ratings are the same, but the sport differs and where the number of value is the greatest. How do I do this?

Example:

```
id  name   rating    sport    value 
 1  Mike    16     football   2002
 2  Sam     85     baseball   2003
 3  Mike    16     baseball   2015
 4  Sam     16     hockey     2004
```

So this should return the row with id=3 (Because Mike=Mike, 16=16, baseball != football, 2015 > 2002)

Comment: You have to try something. SO is not (supposed to be) a code writing service.

Comment: which row would you want returned if two values were the same? ie if both mike's values were '2015'?

Comment: @pala_ In my database I made it impossible for the column value to be the same so this cannot occure

Comment: @Mikelo then the answer i posted below will likely be suitable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably get by with something like this, assuming your table is called `ratings`:

```
select r.* 
  from ratings r
    inner join (
      select name, rating, max(value) value
        from ratings
        group by name, rating
        having count(distinct sport) > 1
    ) q
      on r.name = q.name and r.rating = q.rating and r.value = q.value
```

There are certain situations where this may not produce what you want - ie if someone has the same value for different sports with the same rating. But it fits your use case above at the least.

Comment: btw how do I count the results given by this piece of sql? Adding count(*) in the first select doesn't work properly because it does give back the count but also a few more columns.

Comment: Replace r.* with count and see how it goes

Comment: Okay thnx! Last quick question then, how do I insert the value 1 in the column 'transfer' at all the results? I tried somthing like this but it keeps giving me errors: `INSERT INTO 'isTransfer' VALUES '1' select r.* from players r inner join ( select name, rating, max(id) id from players group by name, rating having count(distinct club) > 1 ) q on r.name = q.name and r.rating = q.rating and r.id = q.id`

Answer (score 0):

Use group by to create groups that have a common name and rating.  Use having count(distinct sport) > 1 to exclude groups that don't have more than one sport.

Without your original SQL code, I can't be any more specific than this.